# Is a comma splice (becoming) acceptable in German?

Tags: punctuation

I have always thought that one aspect of writing in German that causes less angst than writing in English is inner-sentential punctuation. The number of questions about punctuation on StackExchange's [English Language and Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/) site is testimony to this.

In German, for example, independent and dependent clauses must always be separated by commas. There is no such 'rule' in English. But one thing about English that is clear - at least to the extent that considerable attention is given to it in English lessons in school - is that run-ons or comma splices are to be avoided. So, the English teacher will always mark a sentence such as the following as a comma splice mistake:

> The Labour Party is today electing a new leader, the favourite is Tony
>   Blair.

I don't recall having encountered such errors in the British mainstream press that I read - and as an English teacher I am usually hypersensitive to grammar or usage issues.

Yet in today's *Zeit Online* there is an [article](http://www.zeit.de/politik/deutschland/2018-04/spd-parteitag-andrea-nahles-wahl-parteivorsitzende) about the SPD-Parteitag with the following sentence:

> Die SPD wählt eine neue Parteivorsitzende, als gesetzt gilt Andrea
>   Nahles.

And here is a sentence from today's *SPON* [article](http://www.spiegel.de/politik/deutschland/kolumne-jan-fleischhauer-marius-mueller-westernhagen-und-der-echo-a-1203723.html) about antisemitism:

> Er hat nie den Spott aushalten müssen, der sich regelmäßig über
>   Schlagerstars wie Helene Fischer ergießt, dabei trennt die beiden
>   weniger, als man denkt.

It would seem to me that there needs to be a full stop after *ergießt*.

Is this usage generally acceptable practice or simply an example of German journalese to be avoided in other contexts?

Related question: [Is this sentence a run-on sentence?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/7600/is-this-sentence-a-run-on-sentence)

---

**Update: 22.04.2018**

Added more examples from the last two days, plus links to information about comma splices in English from Wikipedia and the influential *OWL at Purdue*:

- Köln und der HSV könnten nun absteigen, das weckt das Schlechte in uns allen. [Source](http://www.zeit.de/sport/2018-04/videobeweis-bundesliga-niko-kovac-martin-kind-hannover-96-bayern-muenchen)
- Der Ölpreis steigt und steigt, das trifft auch amerikanische Verbraucher. [Source](http://www.spiegel.de/wirtschaft/soziales/donald-trump-wir-werden-hoehere-oel-preise-nicht-akzeptieren-a-1203983.html)
- Das heißt nicht, dass sie vorgeben darf, wie das Programm aussieht, sie darf aber den Rahmen setzen, der bei ARD, ZDF und Deutschlandradio mit einer Belegschaft von 41500 „Vollzeitäquivalenten“, 66 Radio-, 21 Fernsehprogrammen und vielerlei Onlineauftritten sehr weit gesteckt ist.  [Source](http://www.faz.net/aktuell/feuilleton/medien/ard-und-zdf-sind-am-ende-mit-ihrem-spar-latein-15552185.html)
- Zuletzt hatte die Polizei die Porsche-Zentrale wegen der Dieselaffäre durchsucht, jetzt wurde ein Mitarbeiter des Autobauers verhaftet. [Source](http://www.zeit.de/wirtschaft/unternehmen/2018-04/abgasskandal-porsche-mitarbeiter-untersuchungshaft)
- Die Sozialdemokraten haben eine neue Chefin gewählt, und dabei hat es wieder einmal gequietscht, wie sollte es anders sein nach diesem fürchterlichen Jahr. [Source](http://www.spiegel.de/politik/deutschland/spd-andrea-nahles-holt-nur-66-prozent-warum-die-partei-nicht-erneuerbar-ist-a-1204209.html)

[Comma Splices 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_splice) - [Comma Splices 2](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/engagement/2/1/34/)

Comment: You seem to be applying English punctuation rules to German sentences. This won't work. English punctuation is driven to improve readability (i.e. aims to improve writing *style*), while in German it is 100% driven by grammar. There are no punctuation "rules" that will tell you where to divide your sentences - As long as the sentences are grammatical, punctuation rules are very clear on where to put your commas and will be fine, however unreadable your text will become. *Style* is an entirely different thing in German writing.

Comment: Adding to _tofro_'s and _Janka_'s comments, I want to mention that there is also the _semicolon_. Personally, I favor the semicolon over the comma in such constructions.

Comment: @Björn Friedrich. Yes, a semi-colon is an acceptable way to separate independent clauses in English.

Comment: @tofro. I think my take-away from your comment and Janka's answer is that most educated English native speakers would consider the comma splice in the English sentence a mistake, whereas most educated German native speakers would not consider the comma splice in the German sentences a problem.

Comment: Das ist im Deutschen tatsächlich nicht unüblich; ich finde trotzdem, dass auch hier das Semikolon eine bessere Wahl als das Komma ist.

Comment: Be careful with semicolons in German, they can seem pretentious and should not be overused. To connect two very short sentences like in the Nahles example, it would be out of place. Thanks, by the way, for making me aware of the "comma splice" rule in English writing; I had never heard of it.

Comment: @Shoe Again: How you build and splice your sentences is not an issue of *punctuation* in German. There are fixed (and much more rigid than in English) rules on where between the grammatical  building blocks you have to put a comma. This is absolutely not a matter of choice. How you build your sentences from grammatical building blocks, however, is a matter of *writing style*. But once you chose the building blocks, punctuation is **fixed**.... (tbc)

Comment: Some of the *style* rules are also entirely different, BTW: While English seems to aim for *readability*, German traditionally seems to follow the rule "If it was complex to think it up and write, it might as well be hard to read".

Comment: @tofro, you can catagorize  the choice between a comma and a full stop as punctuation issue.

Comment: @CarstenS I'm not with you on that. It is a three-step choice: a *stylistic* decision that results in a *grammar* choice which in itself resolves into a *punctuation* issue. ;)

Comment: @tofro, so you are saying that "Die SPD wählt eine neue Parteivorsitzende, als gesetzt gilt Andrea Nahles." and "Die SPD wählt eine neue Parteivorsitzende. Als gesetzt gilt Andrea Nahles." are grammatically different. You can certainly do that, I am just saying that it can also be seen as just different punctuation.

Comment: I agree that your first example essentially amounts to the equivalent of comma splice: an excessive run-on sentence. I think you’re wrong about the second: starting a new sentence with “dabei” would sound odd (although I personally prefer it). (As noted by others, this is of course stylistic, not grammatical.)

Comment: @CarstenS Well, *grammar* says that there *must* be a sentence-delimiter between the two main clauses. This could be a full-stop, a semicolon, a comma, or perhaps an exclamation mark. Between these different *punctuations*, you have a *stylistic* choice. But no punctuation at that point (as well as an unfit sentence-delimiter such as the question mark) are not grammatical, hence not available to chose from. Speaking of question mark: "Wen wählt die SPD als Vorsitzende, als gesetzt gilt Andrea Nahles?" would be awful, only "Wen wählt die SPD als Vorsitzende? Als gesetzt gilt Andrea Nahles." ok.

Comment: @tofro Please as an answer.

Comment: @tofo I like your explanation but why would be the comma in the English example marked as wrong then according to the OP: "The Labour Party is today electing a new leader, the favourite is Tony Blair."

Comment: There's an interesting post on ELU as to whether punctuation is part of grammar. The opinions are divided. My interest on this German site however is on determining whether most German native speakers consider sentences such as those I include here to be perfectly acceptable or not - irrespective of whether it is an issue of grammar or punctuation. https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/388543/are-spelling-punctuation-and-capitalization-part-of-grammar

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> Die SPD wählt eine neue Parteivorsitzende. Als gesetzt gilt Andrea Nahles.
>
> Die SPD wählt eine neue Parteivorsitzende, (und) als gesetzt gilt Andrea Nahles.

These are concatenated main clauses, the comma is **mandatory**. It was always acceptable to do this in German. The form with comma and *und* is taught in schools as this is distinctive from lists with *und*, which by rule don't have the *»Oxford comma«* in German.

In German, you are allowed to run sentences over several pages if you feel to do so.

Comment: Thanks to you and @tofro .It's good to be rid of a misconception about how German Zeichensetzung works. Nevertheless, a sentence such as the following would not strike me as particularly _leserfreundlich_:  _Die SPD wählt eine neue Parteivorsitzende, als gesetzt gilt Andrea Nahles, die gibt sich zuversichtlich, doch laut einer Umfrage sehen die Deutschen sie skeptisch._

Comment: You could write that but it would sound agitated. For that reason, there is the relief with **und**: *… , **und** die gibt sich zuversichtlich …* You could try the reverse and ask German speakers if they heard a comma or a full stop – the answer depends on how you spoke.

Comment: There are also whole books that are just one sentence.

Comment: @PlasmaHH. Yes, _Ulysses_ comes to mind. I was interested to find out that comma splices are not the big no-no for German students in German lessons that they are for English students in English lessons.

Comment: @Janka, this doesn't really answer the question.  With _und_ it's not a comma splice, as that term is understood in English.  The question is whether the _und_ is truly optional.  Including the _und_ is only confusing the issue.

Comment: We can't talk about *comma splice* for German, because this kind of fault does not exist in German. Concatenating independent clauses with commas is allowed and common practice in German, it always was. The *und* is a filler without meaning, it's purely optional.

Comment: *In German, you are allowed to run sentences over several pages if you feel to do so.* always reminds me of a short story by Ephraim Kishin, told in one sentence. Also, Schopenhauer Is notorious for this, just check this sentence starting with *[Wenn man nun, dieses fest haltend, die wichtige Rolle betrachtet, welche die Geschlechtsliebe in allen ihren](http://gutenberg.spiegel.de/buch/die-welt-als-wille-und-vorstellung-zweiter-band-7745/45)* which apparently is [187 words long](http://www.zeit.de/2012/20/Lektion-15-Saetze-Satzlaenge). Needless to say, I didn’t count them myself....

Answer (score 5):

@Janka's answer is perfect, I want to append some detail.

Most of the commas in German are made up by one single rule: Commas have to delimit two complete clauses that come together. A clause is complete as soon as it has a subject and a verb that is conjugated to this subject.

> Die SPD wählt eine neue Parteivorsitzende, als gesetzt gilt Andrea Nahles.

Subject: Die SPD;
Verb: wählt;
Subject: Andrea Nahles;
Verb: gilt.

The second sentence is just a concatenation of two main clauses where you expect a full stop, again the rule subject with conjugated verb (complete clause) applies.

Even more so: The rule you mentioned,

> independent and dependent clauses must always be separated by commas.

is entailed by the rule of complete clauses.

Comment: "The second sentence is just a concatenation of two main clauses where you expect a full stop, again the rule subject with conjugated verb (complete clause) applies."  There's another good example...if it were in German.  ;)  In English you can't do this without a conjunction such as "so" or "thus" or "therefore".